# SQL Pull TY and LY into columns on same row

Tags: sql, date, dynamic, subquery

I am not that great with SQL, but here we go.  I have been trying to pull sku counts for `TY` and `LY` by week and have them in separate columns, but on the same row depending on the other variable...I.e...

```
          Week    TY         LY
ABC        6       30         50
ABC        5      100         20
ABC        4       25         25
```

```
Select
    A.Store,
    B.Week_Num
    COUNT(A.ABC) AS TY,
    COUNT(A.ABC) AS LY
FROM [Table] O360
join Date D on D.Week_num = O360.Week_num
```

The code is simplified above.  The challenge is that I am trying to call for the past 3 Saturdays and the Saturday that is 371 Days before each to represent `LY`....any help would be amazing.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: So `TY` and `LY` are supposed to be???

Comment: Essentially I will be running this weekly.  I will be looking for the past Saturday plus the two before and the Same 3 saturdays from last year.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want `lag()`.  Assuming you have data for every week, then:

```
SELECT t.Store, d.Week_Num,
       COUNT(*) AS TY,
       LAG(COUNT(*), 53) OVER (PARTITION BY t.Store, d.Week_num) AS LY
FROM [Table] t JOIN
     Date D 
     ON D.Week_num = t.Week_num
GROUP BY t.Store, d.Week_Num;
```